# Reverse a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have `"Hello World"` kept in a String variable named `hi`.

I need to print it, but reversed.

How can I do this? I understand there is some kind of a function already built-in into Java that does that.

Related: [Reverse each individual word of “Hello World” string with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-hello-world-in-java)

Comment: @JRL should really be String ih = "dlroW olleH"; System.out.println(ih);

Comment: I wish I could retract my close vote (as a duplicate). I re-read the other question and realized it's subtly different than this. However, this question is still duplicated many times over across the site. Probably ought to just find a different question to mark this a dupe of.

Answer (score 1203, accepted):

You can use this:

```java
new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()
```

`StringBuilder` was added in Java 5.  For versions prior to Java 5, the `StringBuffer` class can be used instead — it has the same API.

Comment: "Thanks commentators for pointing out that StringBuilder is preferred nowadays"? There is a clear statement that StringBuffer if thread-safety is a concern. otherwise, StringBuilder can be used. StringBuilder is not a replacement for StringBuffer.

Comment: @ha9u63ar For this scenario with a local throwaway `StringBuilder` concurrency is not a concern (and I think that's what he meant).

Comment: Here's the link to know the exact difference between the two: http://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder

in short: StringBuilder is **more efficient** than StringBuffer. It's not thread safe i.e. multiple threads can simultaneously call methods of StringBuilder.

Comment: This won't work for Unicode characters outside of BMP, as long as for combining characters.

Comment: @Daniel Brockman, Thank you for your nice and concise answer. Here OP said, _I have "Hello World" kept in a String variable named hi_ . That means `String hi = "Hello World";` . So I think in your answer there should **not** be any double quotes around `hi`. I mean it should be like this `new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()`

Answer (score 123):

For **Online Judges problems** that does not allow `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`, you can do it **in place** using `char[]` as following:

```
public static String reverse(String input){
    char[] in = input.toCharArray();
    int begin=0;
    int end=in.length-1;
    char temp;
    while(end>begin){
        temp = in[begin];
        in[begin]=in[end];
        in[end] = temp;
        end--;
        begin++;
    }
    return new String(in);
}
```

Comment: Just a note though. This will fail horribly for "characters" that occupy two bytes.

Comment: Actually, it typically works fine for most characters that occupy 2 bytes.  What it actually fails for is Unicode codepoints that occupy 2 x 16 bit codeunits (in UTF-16).

Answer (score 71):

```
public static String reverseIt(String source) {
    int i, len = source.length();
    StringBuilder dest = new StringBuilder(len);

    for (i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--){
        dest.append(source.charAt(i));
    }

    return dest.toString();
}
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ReverseStringTest.htm

Comment: Good solution (1+). One enhancement - StringBuilder (since java5) will be faster than StringBuffer. Regards.

Comment: This won't work in the general case as it doesn't take into account that some "characters" in unicode are represented by a surrogate pair i.e. two Java chars, and this solution results in the pair being in the wrong order. The reverse method of StringBuilder should be fine according to the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

Comment: Does it reverse unicode diacriticals in the right order?

Answer (score 68):

```
String string="whatever";
String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(reverse);
```

Comment: What is the complexity of it?  O(N) or more ? N is equal to length of the string.

Comment: O(n) since it has to iterate through the chars of the string at least once.

Answer (score 30):

I am doing this by using the following two ways:

**Reverse string by CHARACTERS:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Using traditional approach
    String result="";
    for(int i=string.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        result = result + string.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(result);

    // Using StringBuffer class
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(string);
    System.out.println(buffer.reverse());    
}
```

**Reverse string by WORDS:**

```
public static void reverseStringByWords(String string) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = string.split(" ");

    for (int j = words.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        stringBuilder.append(words[j]).append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println("Reverse words: " + stringBuilder);
}
```

Comment: better to use `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` for the `result` variable to avoid multiple object creation!

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at the Java 6 API under StringBuffer

```
String s = "sample";
String result = new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: is this better than StringBuilder?

Comment: @CamHart No, it's slower, but probably only a tiny little bit.

Comment: A little benchmark with almost 100 million method calls showed a significant difference between StringBuffer and StringBuilder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer/2771852#2771852 But in this case, there are only two calls (`reverse()` and `toString()`), so the difference probably won't even be measurable.

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example using recursion:

```
public void reverseString() {
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String reverseAlphabet = reverse(alphabet, alphabet.length()-1);
}

String reverse(String stringToReverse, int index){
    if(index == 0){
        return stringToReverse.charAt(0) + "";
    }

    char letter = stringToReverse.charAt(index);
    return letter + reverse(stringToReverse, index-1);
}
```

Comment: There are already far better answers, especially @DanielBrockman's.  If an algorithm already exists in a standard library, there is no need to handcraft it and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: A "far better answer" concept is subjective. This may be exactly what someone is looking for.

Comment: The OP already stated that "there is some kind of a function already built-in into Java that does that" so his goal was to know exactly which "function" this is. Just posting an answer that has little to do with the actual question asked is non-sense. If someone was to ask for a custom implementation your answer would be justified, in this case it is not.

Comment: Downvote. Most other solutions are O(n) and can handle strings of pretty much any length, this one is O(n^2) and tends to crash with a StackOverflowError for strings longer than about 5000 chars (on JDK 8 VM, default config).

Comment: 1. The other solutions don't use recursion and can handle long strings just fine. Why would you use recursion instead of iteration for a task like this? It makes no sense. (Unless you're coming from a functional programming background, which often leads to problems when you're writing code in a imperative/OO language.) 2. String concatenation (that innocent little '+') is O(n). You must be new to Java, otherwise you would know that.

Comment: Here's a good explanation by Jon Skeet of the problem with that little '+' and strings: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html (He's writing about C#, but it's pretty much the same thing in Java.)

Comment: Well, maybe you didn't read http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html , or maybe you didn't understand it. Hint: String concatenation is fine if you create a string in one fell swoop, but not if you build a string in a loop (and in this case, recursion is a loop). Yeah, I do get a bit personal when people post bad code on SO and don't even understand what's bad about it. Good bye.

Answer (score 13):

## Using `charAt()` method

```java
String name = "gaurav";
String reversedString = "";
    
for(int i = name.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    reversedString += name.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(reversedString);
```

## Using `toCharArray()` method

```java
String name = "gaurav";
char [] stringCharArray = name.toCharArray();
String reversedString = "";
    
for(int i = stringCharArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedString += stringCharArray[i];
}

System.out.println(reversedString);
```

## Using `reverse()` method of the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```java
String name = "gaurav";
    
String reversedString = new StringBuilder(name).reverse().toString();
    
System.out.println(reversedString);
```

Check https://coderolls.com/reverse-a-string-in-java/

Answer (score 12):

Here is a low level solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inpStr = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Original String :" + inpStr);
        char temp;
        char[] arr = inpStr.toCharArray();
        int len = arr.length;
        for(int i=0; i<(inpStr.length())/2; i++,len--){
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[len-1];
            arr[len-1] = temp;
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse String :" + String.valueOf(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I tried, just for fun, by using a Stack. Here my code:

```
public String reverseString(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
    }
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        sb.append(stack.pop());
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Since the below method (using **XOR**) to *reverse a string* is not listed, I am attaching this method to reverse a string.

The **Algorithm** is based on :

> 1.(A XOR B) XOR B = A
>
> 2.(A XOR B) XOR A = B

Code snippet:

```
public class ReverseUsingXOR {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "prateek";
        reverseUsingXOR(str.toCharArray());
    }   

    /*Example:
     * str= prateek;
     * str[low]=p;
     * str[high]=k;
     * str[low]=p^k;
     * str[high]=(p^k)^k =p;
     * str[low]=(p^k)^p=k;
     * 
     * */
    public static void reverseUsingXOR(char[] str) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = str.length - 1;

        while (low < high) {
            str[low] = (char) (str[low] ^ str[high]);
            str[high] = (char) (str[low] ^ str[high]);   
            str[low] = (char) (str[low] ^ str[high]);
            low++;
            high--;
        }

        //display reversed string
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(str[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

keetarp

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out the preferred way is to use:

```
new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()
```

But if you want to implement this by yourself, I'm afraid that the rest of responses have flaws.

The reason is that `String` represents a list of **Unicode** points, encoded in a `char[]` array according to the variable-length encoding: [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

This means some code points use a single element of the array (one code unit) but others use two of them, so there might be pairs of characters that must be treated as a single unit (consecutive "high" and "low" surrogates).

```
public static String reverseString(String s) {
    char[] chars = new char[s.length()];
    boolean twoCharCodepoint = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        chars[s.length() - 1 - i] = s.charAt(i);
        if (twoCharCodepoint) {
            swap(chars, s.length() - 1 - i, s.length() - i);
        }
        twoCharCodepoint = !Character.isBmpCodePoint(s.codePointAt(i));
    }
    return new String(chars);
}

private static void swap(char[] array, int i, int j) {
    char temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/reverse-string.txt");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Linear B Syllable B008 A: ");
    sb.appendCodePoint(65536); //http://unicode-table.com/es/#10000
    sb.append(".");
    fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-16"));
    fos.write("\n".getBytes("UTF-16"));
    fos.write(reverseString(sb.toString()).getBytes("UTF-16"));
}
```

Comment: Good solution, only part missing is now handling of combining diacritics :-D

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple in minimum code of lines

```
public class ReverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "neelendra";
        for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to write this now.. Found you have already written it !

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = (text.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**1. Using Character Array:**

```
public String reverseString(String inputString) {
    char[] inputStringArray = inputString.toCharArray();
    String reverseString = "";
    for (int i = inputStringArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseString += inputStringArray[i];
    }
    return reverseString;
}
```

**2. Using StringBuilder:**

```
public String reverseString(String inputString) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(inputString);
    stringBuilder = stringBuilder.reverse();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

OR

```
return new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();

String reverse = new StringBuffer(name).reverse().toString();
String rev = reverse.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(rev);
```

I used this method to turn names backwards and into lower case.

Answer (score 2):

One natural way to reverse a `String` is to use a `StringTokenizer` and a stack. `Stack` is a class that implements an easy-to-use last-in, first-out (LIFO) stack of objects.

```
String s = "Hello My name is Sufiyan";
```

Put it in the stack frontwards

```
Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     myStack.push(st.nextToken());
}
```

Print the stack backwards

```
System.out.print('"' + s + '"' + " backwards by word is:\n\t\"");
while (!myStack.empty()) {
  System.out.print(myStack.pop());
  System.out.print(' ');
}

System.out.println('"');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public String reverse(String s) {

        String reversedString = "";
        for(int i=s.length(); i>0; i--) {
            reversedString += s.charAt(i-1);
        }   

        return reversedString;
    }
```

Comment: Again, surrogate pairs will become corrupted with this way.

Comment: @JamesSmith could you expand on this please?

Comment: Some unicode characters consist of two characters; if these two are switched around, the string is corrupted. Also, one commonly overlooked error is regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
public class StringReverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Dogs hates cats";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
        System.out.println(sb.reverse());
    }
}
```

Comment: there are many method to reverse a string.this is one of them using stringbuffer class of java.accepted answer is using diff class to reverse which is not available in older version of JDK.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
   StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("Game Plan");
   buffer.reverse();
   System.out.println(buffer);
 }  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

All above solution is too good but here I am making reverse string using recursive programming.

This is helpful for who is looking recursive way of doing reverse string.

```
public class ReversString {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    char s[] = "Dhiral Pandya".toCharArray();
    String r = new String(reverse(0, s));
    System.out.println(r);
}

public static char[] reverse(int i, char source[]) {

    if (source.length / 2 == i) {
        return source;
    }

    char t = source[i];
    source[i] = source[source.length - 1 - i];
    source[source.length - 1 - i] = t;

    i++;
    return reverse(i, source);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Procedure :

We can use split() to split the string .Then use reverse loop and add the characters.

---

### Code snippet:

```
class test
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
      String str = "world";
      String[] split= str.split("");

      String revers = "";
      for (int i = split.length-1; i>=0; i--)
      {
        revers += split[i];
      }
      System.out.printf("%s", revers);
   }  
}

 //output : dlrow
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Sequence of characters (or) String<sup>[String's Family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47454051/5081877)</sup>:

```
String testString = "Yashwanth@777"; // ~1 1⁄4→D800₁₆«2²⁰
```

> Using **Java 8 Stream API**

First we convert String into stream by using method `CharSequence.chars()`, then we use the method `IntStream.range` to generate a sequential stream of numbers. Then we map this sequence of stream into String.

```java
public static String reverseString_Stream(String str) {
    IntStream cahrStream = str.chars();
    final int[] array = cahrStream.map( x -> x ).toArray();

    int from = 0, upTo = array.length;
    IntFunction<String> reverseMapper = (i) -> ( Character.toString((char) array[ (upTo - i) + (from - 1) ]) );

    String reverseString = IntStream.range(from, upTo) // for (int i = from; i < upTo ; i++) { ... }
            .mapToObj( reverseMapper )                 // array[ lastElement ]
            .collect(Collectors.joining())             // Joining stream of elements together into a String.
            .toString();                               // This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.

    System.out.println("Reverse Stream as String : "+ reverseString);
    return reverseString;
}
```

> Using a Traditional for Loop

If you want to reverse the string then we need to follow these steps.

- Convert String into an Array of Characters.
- Iterate over an array in reverse order, append each Character to temporary string variable until the last character.

```java
public static String reverseString( String reverse ) {
    if( reverse != null && reverse != "" && reverse.length() > 0 ) {

        char[] arr = reverse.toCharArray();
        String temp = "";
        for( int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            temp += arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Reverse String : "+ temp);
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Easy way to Use reverse method provided form StringBuffer or StringBuilder Classes

StringBuilder and StringBuffer are mutable sequence of characters. That means one can change the value of these object's.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(str);
System.out.println("StringBuffer - reverse : "+ buffer.reverse() );

String builderString = (new StringBuilder(str)).reverse().toString;
System.out.println("StringBuilder generated reverse String : "+ builderString  );
```

StringBuffer has the same methods as the StringBuilder, but each method in StringBuffer is synchronized so it is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String revString(String str){
    char[] revCharArr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i< str.length()/2; i++){
        char f = revCharArr[i];
        char l = revCharArr[str.length()-i-1];
        revCharArr[i] = l;
        revCharArr[str.length()-i-1] = f;
    }
    String revStr = new String(revCharArr);
    return revStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple For loop in java

```
 public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    int length = s.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length / 2; i++) {
        // swaping character
        char temp = s[length - i - 1];
        s[length - i - 1] = s[i];
        s[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Java does not provide a general solution to reversing a String due to the "surrogate pairs" problem, which you have to allow for.

If the requirement is that it is guaranteed to work for all Unicode and in all languages (including Welsh :), then you have to roll your own. Just do an in-place array swap of the string as its code points:

```
public static String reverse(String str)
{
        // You get what you ask for ;)
        if (str == null) return null;

        // str.length() is equal to the number of unicode code points in a string
        if (str.isEmpty() || str.length() == 1) return str;

        final int[] codePoints = str.codePoints().toArray();
        final int len = codePoints.length;

        // swap in place
        for(int i = 0; i < codePoints.length/2; i++)
        {
            int tmp = codePoints[i];
            codePoints[i] = codePoints[len-i-1];
            codePoints[len-i-1] = tmp;
        }

        return new String(codePoints,0,len);
}
```

If you do this by using String.getBytes(), then all the bytes will be reversed, which will reverse all UTF-8 encodings, and any attempt using a Character that isn't an int code point will fail with any "astral plane" code points (those outside the BMP).

As a general solution this is reasonably efficient, but it is extremely simple and guaranteed to work for any string, which is probably want you want from a "general solution".

The only gotcha is if you read the String out of a UTF8/16 encoded file, you might have a BOM at the start, but that's outside the scope of the question.

-Blue

Answer (score 0):

Using apache.commons.lang3

```
StringUtils.reverse(hi)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str = "Hello World";

        char[] strCharArr = str.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0, k= strCharArr.length-1;i != k; i++, k--) {
            char temp = strCharArr[i];
            strCharArr[i] = strCharArr[k];
            strCharArr[k] = temp;
        }

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(strCharArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet suggested, you can also concatenate `hi` to an empty string and reverse it like:

```java
"".concat(hi).reverse()
```

This is also valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The following Solution worked for me

```
public class ReverseString {
public static void reverseString(char[] s) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] input = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    reverseString(input);
    System.out.println(new String(input)); // Output: "olleh"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Prashant";
    int len = str.length();
    char[] c = new char[len];
    for (int j = len - 1, i = 0; j >= 0; j--, i++) {
        c[i] = str.charAt(j);
    }
    str = String.copyValueOf(c);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Any answer to this question that *doesn't* use a built-in `reverse()` method is basically a wrong answer.

Comment: Agreed, especially as these "simple" solutions don't take into account surrogate pairs and can actually corrupt the string - see my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

It gets the value you typed and returns it reversed ;)

```
public static  String reverse (String a){
    char[] rarray = a.toCharArray();
    String finalvalue = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < rarray.length; i++)
    {
        finalvalue += rarray[rarray.length - 1 - i];
    }   
return finalvalue;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

public String reverseWords(String s) {

```
    String reversedWords = "";

    if(s.length()<=0) {
        return reversedWords;
    }else if(s.length() == 1){
        if(s == " "){
            return "";
        }
        return s;
    }

    char arr[] = s.toCharArray();
    int j = arr.length-1;
    while(j >= 0 ){
        if( arr[j] == ' '){
            reversedWords+=arr[j];
        }else{
            String temp="";
            while(j>=0 && arr[j] != ' '){
                temp+=arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            j++;
            temp = reverseWord(temp);
            reversedWords+=temp;
        }
        j--;

    }

    String[] chk = reversedWords.split(" ");

    if(chk == null || chk.length == 0){
        return "";
    }

    return reversedWords;



}

public String reverseWord(String s){

    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0,j=arr.length-1;i<=j;i++,j--){
        char tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
    return String.valueOf(arr);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("racecar");
    for (int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1; i < (s.length()/2); i++, j--) {
        char temp = s.charAt(i);
        s.setCharAt(i, s.charAt(j));
        s.setCharAt(j, temp);
    }

    System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void reverString(){
System.out.println("Enter value");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 try{

  String str=br.readLine();
  char[] charArray=str.toCharArray();
  for(int i=charArray.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   System.out.println(charArray[i]);
  }
  }
   catch(IOException ex){
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

recursion:

```
 public String stringReverse(String string) {
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return string;
    }
    return stringReverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to reverse a string.

*1. Converting String into Bytes: getBytes() method is used to convert the input string into bytes[].*

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class ReverseString{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "GeeksforGeeks";
    byte [] strAsByteArray = input.getBytes();
    byte [] result =  new byte [strAsByteArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i<strAsByteArray.length; i++)
        result[i] = 
         strAsByteArray[strAsByteArray.length-i-1];

    System.out.println(new String(result));
}
}
```

*2.Converting String to character array: The user input the string to be reversed.* **(Personally suggested)**

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class ReverseString{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "GeeksForGeeks";

    // convert String to character array
    // by using toCharArray
    char[] try1 = input.toCharArray();

    for (int i = try1.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        System.out.print(try1[i]);
}
}
```

*3.Using ArrayList object: Convert the input string into the character array by using toCharArray() built in method. Then, add the characters of the array into the ArrayList object. Java also has built in reverse() method for the Collections class. Since Collections class reverse() method takes a list object , to reverse the list , we will pass the LinkedList object which is a type of list of characters.*

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

 class ReverseString{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "Geeks For Geeks";
    char[] hello = input.toCharArray();
    List<Character> trial1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char c: hello)
        trial1.add(c);

    Collections.reverse(trial1);
    ListIterator li = trial1.listIterator();
    while (li.hasNext())
        System.out.print(li.next());
}
}
```