# how to revearse a string?

Tags: java, string, reverse

Cant seem to get this to work. trying to get it to read backwards like a mirror without using the buffer class.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {



   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in); 

   System.out.println("Enter a phrase:");

   String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
   String Rphrase;

   int n = phrase.length();
   int r = 0;

   do{
        n--; r++;
    Rphrase[r] = phrase[n];

  }while(n >= 0);


   System.out.println(Rphrase);
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in the code you've posted. I highly recommend you remove everything and start over. This is simply done by 1.) reading in the `String` 2.) converting the `String` to an `array` of `chars` 3.) using a `for-loop` to iterate through the `char[]` backwards.

Comment: String rPhrase = new StringBuilder(phrase).reverse().toString();

Comment: @Tdorno: And what made you think he's using a library?

Comment: It appears to be a class name! Rphrase is a variable here :D The importance of camelCasing :)

Comment: @Sujay Ah, my bad Rphrase shows incorrectly because he capitalized it. But the approach is still awful. =D

Comment: Thank you all for the help and advise. I see that its evident to all of you that i have only been coding for a month lol. Ill make sure to camelCase my variables for now on. It looks like i was trying to call on the string as if it were an array not a string. Its fixed now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided 4 ways of getting the output of the String reversed.

## Option 1:

Just iterate the String backwards.

```
for (int i=phrase.length()-1; i>-1; i--) { 
    System.out.print(foo.charAt(i));  
}
```

## Option 2:

If you would like to put it in the other buffer you can do:

```
char[] buffer = new char[phrase.length()];
index = 0;
for (int i=phrase.length()-1; i>-1; i--) { 
    buffer[index++] = foo.charAt(i);  
}
```

## Option 3:

You said you didnt want to use the buffer class (which I think you're referring to **StringBuffer** so I'm assuming you dont want to use **StringBuilder** either) so here is how you can do it strictly with Strings (which is rather inefficient, because a new String is constructed each iteration):

```
String foo = "";
for (int i=phrase.length()-1; i>-1; i--) { 
    foo += foo.charAt(i);  
}
```

## Option 4:

A most likely more **efficient** way of doing this though, is by using **StringBuilder**:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(foo.length());
for (int i=foo.length()-1; i>-1; i--) {
    sb.append(foo.charAt(i));
}
String reverse = sb.toString();
```

### OR

Refer to this for *very simple* String reversal with a **StringBuilder**:
[Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in); 

    System.out.println("Enter a phrase:");

    String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
    String rPhrase = "";
    for (int i = phrase.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        rPhrase += phrase.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(rPhrase);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let the OP figure out the problem and then fix the problem on his own? Rather then just doing it for him?

Comment: If you're going to write it for him, don't keep the `Rphrase` variable name, always start variables with lower case letters.

Comment: @Tdorno I guess so.. But it's too late, sry :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
String reverse = "";
String toReverse = "hello";

for(int i = 0; i<toReverse.length();i++){
    reverse += toReverse.substring(i,i+1);
}

System.out.println(reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints, rather than a complete solution...

Your loop will run for one more iteration when `n = 0`, which will lead to trying to access index `-1`. So perhaps try `n > 0` as your condition.

And what would happen if the string is empty? It would also try to access index `-1`, before ever getting to the loop. Perhaps you should put the condition at the beginning.

`String` doesn't support the `[]` operator - try:

```
Rphrase += phrase.charAt(n);
```

In which case you may as well get rid of `r`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a decrement so it can read its value back to front

for (int i = name.length() - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            newName[j] = name.charAt(i);  `enter code here`

}

```
    System.out.println(newName);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simply use StringBuilder.reverse

```
str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```