# string printing reference in java

Tags: java, string

I have this code where I am printing a string variable. The first output is showing what is expected but the second time it prints some unreadable output(I think its reference id). Please explain: Why does this happen?

```
public class Str3 {
    public String frontBack(String str) {
        char c[] = str.toCharArray();
        char temp = c[0];
        c[0] = c[c.length - 1];
        c[c.length - 1] = temp;
        return c.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Str3 s = new Str3();
        String s1 = new String("boy");
        System.out.println(s1);
        String s2 = s.frontBack("boy");
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

Output:

> boy
>
> [C@60aeb0

Answer (score 2):

the frontToBack() method is calling `toString()` on a character array object `char[]` which is why you see the `[C@60aebo`. Instead of calling `toString()` return with `new String(c);` or `String.valueOf(c)`

Answer (score 0):

Array types in Java do not override `Object#toString()`. In other words, array types inherit `Object`'s implementation of `toString()` which is just

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

which is the output you see

```
[C@60aeb0
```

If you want to see a representation of the contents of an array, use `Arrays.toString(..)`.

In your case, you seem to want to switch the first and last characters and return the corresponding string. In that case, just create a new `String` instance by passing the `char[]` to the constructor.

Comment: so if i want to override toString in my class can you show me , what code to ride please?

Comment: @user just write a method to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a custom class to do this. The functionality is already in java.
This question has already been answered @ [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)
(duplicate thread)

Comment: in short -> new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()
or for versions earlier than JDK 1.5, use java.util.StringBuffer

Answer (score 0):

use new String(c) to c.toString();

c.toString()  c mean array of chars toString() print hash method

```
public class Str3 {

public String frontBack(String str) {
    char c[] = str.toCharArray();

    char temp = c[0];

    c[0] = c[c.length - 1];

    c[c.length - 1] = temp;

    return new String(c);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Str3 s = new Str3();

    String s1 = new String("boy");

    System.out.println(s1);

    String s2 = s.frontBack("boy");

    System.out.println(s2);

}   }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution...easy to understand and works!!