# how to reverse a string with out using charAt()

Tags: java, string

how to  reverse a string without using inbuilt functions not even charAt() ?
I was asked this at an interview and cannot find the solution.

I'm sure he didn't mean to use string buffer , he specifically said no inbuilt functions at all, not even CharAt().

the  language is java

Comment: if u did the home work it would be great if u share the solution

Comment: if you got answer of this question, please let me know. I am really curios about the solution. As far as I know, do not using any of inbuilt method, it is impossible to do anything

Comment: yes juneyoung may be point was to point out this only ..that it cannot be done

Answer (score 1):

> how to reverse a string without using inbuilt functions not even

By using the algorithm reverse? I'm assuming c++ here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string s  = "Hallo";

    reverse( s.begin(), s.end() );
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints "ollaH"

If you're language is JavaScript, it also seems to have a reverse method on arrays...

> The OP indicated that he is using java, in that case [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java) holds the answer you're looking for:

Comment: no inbuilt functions means u cannot use begin or end and i'm using java

Comment: See my modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can reverse String via byte Array.

note that if you use another character, 
you should specify char-set as a parameter of getBytes(String).

Here is my solution >>

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "String";
        byte[] byteArr = string.getBytes();
        byte[] secondByteArr = new byte[byteArr.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < byteArr.length ; i++){
            secondByteArr[(byteArr.length - 1) - i] = byteArr[i];
        }

        System.out.println(new String(secondByteArr));
    }
}
```

good luck with that:D

Comment: but then getBytes is also and inbuilt function ?

Comment: However, if you do not want to inbuilt method, you should not use types like string also. it is a part of String Object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can transform it to CharArray and reverse it from top-down for loop

```
String s = "abcdef";
char c[] = s.toCharArray();

for( int i = c.length -1; i>=0; i--)
    System.out.print(c[i]);
```