# java-reversing order of characters in string

Tags: java, reverse

I am trying to write a simple method that reverse the characters of a string. I need someone to help me correct this.

```
public String backward(String s){
        String str=new String();
        String str2=s;
        char[] c=str.toCharArray();
        for (int i=c.length-1;i>=0;i--)
            str+=c[i];
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=reverse%20order%20of%20string%20java and make sure you use something like a `StringBuilder`

Comment: details. What are your errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: And also get rid of i >= 0 in for loop. This should be i > -1. Reason: i >= 0 takes 3 operations, i > 0 ?, i == 0 ? and logical OR for the 2 results; i > -1 is just a single operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char[] c=**str2**.toCharArray();

str2, not str

or just **s**

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringBuilder's built-in reverse() method and then print the output. The method will iterate through each word in the source string, reverse it.
For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner newStrng = new Scanner(System.in);
String reverString = new StringBuilder(newStrng).reverse.toString();
System.println.out(reverString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char[] c=str.toCharArray();
```

to

```
char[] c=s.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Stringbuilder`, append you text and call the `reverse` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the String objects "charAt" method:

```
String str = "hello world";
String newString = "";
for(int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++){
newString += str.charAt(str.length() - i);
}
System.out.println(newString);
```