# how to reverse an inputted number

Tags: java, loops

I want to reverse an inputted number. I've written the code for it. But i need to know if it could have been done in any other much faster way. Please feel free to modify my code.

```
public static void main()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int num=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    int no=num;
    int d;
    int rev_no=0;
    int digits=0;
    while(num>0)
    {
        num/=10;
        digits++;
    }
    while(no>0)
    {
        d=no%10;
        rev_no+=d*(Math.pow(10,(digits-1)));
        no/=10;
        digits--;
    }
    System.out.println(rev_no);
}
```

Comment: Convert it to a string, [reverse it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java), and convert it back to an `int`(if it's necessary).

Comment: but it's probably same complexity :)

Comment: This is probably better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Mysterion, not really. It can look nicer, but just to show how while compressing it all into a single line to fit into the comments: Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(new Integer(123456789))).reverse().toString());

Comment: @OferLando this fails if the result of the reversed `int` doesn't fit in `int` values e.g. try reversing `2147483647`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza PSB: the question didn't ask about bigger values, but regardless, this can be resolved using BigInteger just as well.

Comment: @OferLando I suggest you to check the most voted answer from the duplicate Q/A.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's nice, but it's actually more complicated.

Comment: @OferLando it's the same algorithm OP's following but use a `long` to store the result, then check if the resultant `long` is between a valid `int` value and handle this case. I don't see how this is *more complicated*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I didn't say it is more complicated than what Sanjay documented - it is more complicated that what Christian and I suggested. But anyway, OP's question was answered, so this discussion is pretty much redundant.

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian mentioned above in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
int originalInt = 123456789;
String str = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(originalInt)).reverse().toString();
int reversedInt = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(new Integer(123456789))).reverse().toString());
```

**EDIT:**

To answer @Luiggi Mendoza's concern - supporting numbers that are too big to fit an Integer can be done using BigInteger as follows:

```
BigInteger originalValue = BigInteger.valueOf(563463346233535772l);
String reversedString = new StringBuilder(originalValue.toString()).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: As shown in my comment, this breaks if the result doesn't fit in an `int` e.g. 2147483647.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And how is OP's original code exempt from that limitation?

Comment: It is not and OP's code is wrong as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But he just wants to revert an int. That's what he asks for.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Exactly.  Why are you bringing it up?  If OP is using an `int`, then I think we can assume the input will fall under the maximum value for an `int`.

Comment: @mittmemo Ok, test this: 2147483643

Comment: @c0dev if you test reversing a valid `int` input that returns an invalid `int` output then you will get an unhandled exception.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - to answer your concern, I added another option, using BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myNum=num.toString();
String reversed = new StringBuffer(myNum).reverse().toString();
num=Integer.parseInt(reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example without StringBuilder.

```
private static long revert(long number){
    String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);

    String[] splitted = numberAsString.split("");

    String returnString = "";

    for(int i = splitted.length-1; i >=0; i--){
        returnString += splitted[i];
    }

    return Integer.valueOf(returnString);
}
```