# A while loop with an if statement and a for loop in it

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a small program where I can have the program read in a word. If the word has 6 letters, display the word backwards. 
If not, tell the user how many letters the word has. Do this until the user enters “japan”.

The example output is:

> Enter a word > chess
>
> chess has 5 letters
>
> Enter a word > google
>
> Magic six! ELGOOG
>
> Enter a word > japan
>
> Goodbye!

The if statement and the for loop are bypassed for some reason and I'm not sure why. My current code is as such:

```
import java.util.*; //imports the utilities
public class WordPyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word: "); 

        while ((n = kb.nextLine().toLowerCase()) == "japan" ) {
            int y = n.length();
            {
                if (y == 6) {
                    String reverse = "";

                    for (int i = y - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        reverse = reverse + n.charAt(i);
                        System.out.println(reverse);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(n + " has " + y + 1 + " letters ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now what's your specific problem with this code?

Comment: And? What is your question? Btw: you should re-check on how to compare strings in Java.

Comment: The if statement and the for loop are bypassed fro some reason and I 'n not sure why

Comment: Btw, [reverse a string on Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Luiggi and Tom, My code is not doing what is reuqired of it and I'm not sure why, none of the fixes below have worked and thus I need assistance. Please Help

Comment: Have you still yet to figure out an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:
`kb.next()` instead of `kb.nextLine()`

Also, to compare to String object you have to use `equals()` like: 
`while ((n = kb.nextLine().toLowerCase()).equals("japan")) {`

Comment: `Scanner#nextLine` is not wrong. It reads the whole line rather than a simple *word* .

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza told why

Comment: I already say it: it reads the whole line and rather than reading a simple *word* e.g. if your input is *hello world* then `Scanner#nextLine` will return `"hello world"` while `Scanner#next` will return `"hello"` only. Also, `Scanner#next` doesn't consume the character(s) entered by pressing Enter key in the input stream.

Comment: Also, the condition in the `while` loop should be with a not equals.

Comment: The program still doesnt output the correct output

Comment: This change* doesn't make sense to me, because it won't fix the issues OP has stated and the sentence `"Enter a word: "` doesn't indicate that the user should be able to enter different words, delimited by white space. But keep it if you think it help ... (* the `#nextLine` -> `#next` change)

Comment: Luiggi and Tom, My code is not doing what is reuqired of it and I'm not sure why, none of the fixes below have worked and thus I need assistance. Please Help