# String display same as it is in reverse order

Tags: java

Team,

I want java program to display string same as it is in reverse order.

Example:
Input:
I am hulli.
Output:
hulli am I

Please can help me this program.

Comment: SO what you tried? Did you even tried to search in Google ?

Comment: Ya i didn't find anyhing.

Comment: Can u help, i want program without using Lib function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the original string and put it back together by iterating the array from end to start:

```
String str = "I am hulli";
String[] parts = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(parts[parts.length - 1]);

// Assume there's at least one world in str
result.append(parts[parts.length - 1]); 
for (int i = parts.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    result.append(" ").append(parts[i]);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: we need to compulsory StringBuilder class?

Comment: Wouldn't initialising the StringBuilder to the length of str be slightly more efficient?

Comment: can u explain me how to do it.

Comment: @NamelessVoice Your're probably right. I originally didn't want to clatter up my answer with it, but it's really a minor change, I'll just edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
import java.util.*;

class ReverseString
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String original, reverse = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
      original = in.nextLine();

      int length = original.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

      System.out.println("Reverse: "+reverse);
   }
}
```

Comment: Andrew this program will not return same as i need

Comment: What do you mean? it gives you the reverse order.

Comment: O i see what you mean. Well you already have you answer, so i guess i was to late

Answer (score 0):

You could use on of the many functions prerolled into the Java Collections Framework. Something like this will make use of this function to display the string in reverse order.

```
String text = "i am hulli";
String[] eachWord = text.split(" ").trim();

List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>(eachWord.length);

for (int i = 0; i < eachWord.length; i++) {
   sentence.add(eachWord[i]);
}

Collections.reverse(sentence);

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
   System.out.print(sentence.get(i) + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: How do i rate for best answer

Comment: select the opaque checkmark next to the answer.