# Name in Reverse

Tags: java

Hello I have the following string but cant seem to get it to display the word entered in original form as well as its reverse form together.

NameemaN

Can someone please help?

```
import java.util.*;

class ReverseString
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String Nombre, reverse = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Anota tu Nombre");
      Nombre = in.nextLine();

      int length = Nombre.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + Nombre.charAt(i);

      System.out.println("Tu nombre alrevez: " + reverse);
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @wadda_wadda I don't believe it is a dup as the OP is not asking for logic to reverse a string.

Answer (score 2):

You're not printing it forward first so it will only print in reverse.

Try changing the print statement to...

`System.out.println("Tu nombre alrevez: " + Nombre + reverse);`