# how to inverse a string

Tags: java, arrays

I have this homework from the school, however Im not sure Im doing wrong the second array does not takes the values of the first one, can you help me please?

```
public static void main(String[] rpp) {

        String[] word = new String[7];        
        word[0] = "D";
        word[1] = "E";
        word[2] = "N";
        word[3] = "T";
        word[4] = "I";
        word[5] = "S";
        word[6] = "T";        

        String[] inverseWord = new String[7];
        inverseWord[0] = "";
        inverseWord[1] = "";
        inverseWord[2] = "";
        inverseWord[3] = "";
        inverseWord[4] = "";
        inverseWord[5] = "";       


        for(int x = word.length;x <= 0;x--){
            for(int y = 0;y <= word.length;y++){
                inverseWord[y] = word[x];                
            }            
        }        
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(inverseWord) + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: this is a duplicate of a dozen other reverse string questions, did you even look for an existing answer?

Comment: I think he is asking how to fix his code rather than asking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Common use is to name iterator values `i`, `j`, `k`, ..., not `x` or `y`, unless they have special meaning as coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Array-indexes start at 0. Which means that if the length is L, the last index in the array will be (L-1).

This means that instead of `int x = word.length` you need to write `int x = word.length - 1` and instead of `y <= word.length` you need to write `y < word.length` or `y <= word.length - 1`.

Also, the condition in your outer loop should be `x >= 0`, not `x <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need two `for` loops
2. `x` should be greater than equal to 0 not less than

```
public static void main(String[] rpp) {
    String[] word = new String[7];
    word[0] = "D";
    word[1] = "E";
    word[2] = "N";
    word[3] = "T";
    word[4] = "I";
    word[5] = "S";
    word[6] = "T";

    String[] inverseWord = new String[7];
    inverseWord[0] = "";
    inverseWord[1] = "";
    inverseWord[2] = "";
    inverseWord[3] = "";
    inverseWord[4] = "";
    inverseWord[5] = "";

    for (int x = word.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        inverseWord[(word.length-1) - x] = word[x];
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(inverseWord) + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition on your outer for loop should be

x >= 0

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the for loop used for reversing using 2 variables.This is the simplest and most basic method.

```
 for(int i=word.length-1,int j=0;i>=0,j>=0;i--,j++) //loop for reversing
            {
                inverseWord[j] = word[i];
            }

    for(int i=0;i>=0;i++) // for displaying the inverseword array
    {
    System.out.print(inverseWord[j];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to append individual characters into a String. The String "DENTIST" can be broken up into characters of reverse order with the use of the charAt method in the String class and a for loop.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "DENTIST";
        StringBuilder inverseWord = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = word.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            inverseWord.append(word.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(inverseWord);

    }

}
```

Comment: TO be honest, if I already use `StringBuilder`, when I would use `String inverseWord = new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();` and I'm done.