# How to Display the text in Reverse from char to String

Tags: android, textview, reverse

[image]
I tried to display the text but it is displaying in wrong view. I want to display the `Textview` in reverse. I tried this code

```java
String subMenuId = (String) key[position];
String subMenuName = subMenuTable.get(subMenuId);
for (int x = 0; x < subMenuName.length(); x++) {
    int splitword = subMenuName.charAt(x);
    char c = (char) splitword;
    TextView product = new TextView(con);
    product.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    product.setRotation(-90);
    holder.tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    product.setTextSize(12);
    holder.tv.setPadding(5,0,5,0);
    product.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    product.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    holder.tv.addView(product);
}
```

Comment: by reverse you mean to say LIKE should be displayed EKIL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: yes, check the image above, it's my result. i want to display it in reverse

Comment: Do you want a single `TextView` with 90° rotated? or each character  as textview as in your code?

Comment: see the image i uploaded. it shows like "nairategeV". its actually vegetarian. but it's displaying like that. i want to display it as Vegetarian in that image

Comment: change your loop to  `for (int x = subMenuName.length() -1; x >=0 ; x--)` :)

Comment: thank u so much it's working

Comment: I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse your loop

i.e.

```java
for (int x = 0; x < subMenuName.length(); x++)
```

to

```java
for (int x = subMenuName.length() -1; x >=0 ; x--)
```

Hope it helps

When you iterate from `0` ⇢ `n` first char get referred first and will be added to top. since you want it in reverse, iterate `n` ⇢ `0`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

`String reversedString = new StringBuilder("LIKE").reverse().toString()`