# String Index OutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, reverse, indexoutofboundsexception

My assignment is to reverse a string and print the reversed string.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class reverse1
{
  public static void reverse(String x) throws IllegalCharacterException
  {
    char j;
    int max;
    String reversedString = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length() - 1; i++)
    {
      max = x.length();
      j = x.charAt(i);
      j = reversedString.charAt(max);
      i--;
    }//end for loop

   }//end method

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalCharacterException
 {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String s;
   System.out.println("Please enter a string");
   s = keyboard.next();
   reverse(s);
 }//end main

}//end class
```

I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at reverse1.reverse(reverse1.java:14)
at reverse1.main(reverse1.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I had checked the line numbers mentioned but still don't understand the problem. I did change the x.length() to x.length() - 1 because a friend had told me to do that, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: `reversedString.charAt(max);`... What did you expect this to return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @cricket_007: Why duplicate of "Reverse a string in Java"? The question is not about how to reverse a string. It is about a particular exception.

Comment: @yaccob "How do I do this?" is a better question than "why is there an exception", no?

Comment: thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line`j = reversedString.charAt(max);` is giving you error.Since `reversedString` conatins empty string of length zero.But you are accessing `max` index from that.

Note:The logic you have written for reversing string is not correct.Below code may help on that

```
for(int i = x.length() - 1; i >=0 ; i--)
{
  char c = x.charAt(i);
  reversedString = reversedString+c;
}
```

Comment: @Marc If this answer helps please consider accepting it..(y)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
String reversedString = " ";
```

After a few lines you write:

```
j = reversedString.charAt(max); // while the reversedString.length() == 1
```

That's why you get your error. You've confused `x.length()` which you've inputed to `max` (6 apperently) and reversedString which always equals " " and never has a length higher than 1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you are writing a program to reverse a string. But at the first glance, I think you are far from the solution.

*But don't worry!* The reason why the exception is thrown is that you are getting the character at the `max` index in the string " ". The string " " only has one character - a space. This means that it only has one index, 0. If you try to access the character at index 6 or 7 or 8 or some value other than 0, you get an exception!

Why not use the reverse method provided in the `StringBuilder` class? It is *insanely* easy to use! Put this code in your `reverse` method:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(x);
builder.reverse();
x = builder.toString();
System.out.println(x);
```

Let's look at this line by line.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(x);
```

This creates a new `StringBuilder` with an initial string of `x`, the argument passed into the method.

```
builder.reverse();
```

This line reverses the string in the `StringBuilder`, aka `x`.

```
x = builder.toString();
```

This assigns the reversed string to `x`.

```
System.out.println(x);
```

You know, just prints the reversed string.

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, please consider accepting it by clicking that tick. @Marc

Answer (score -1):

`reversedString` has an initial length of 1, so its' initial maximum valid index will be 0. For any string `x` longer than 0 (any non-empty string) `max = x.length()` will cause a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in the first iteration.