# Reverse each line of the inputs in java

Tags: java

My code cannot reverse each line of the input.
It should be look like:
Input:

> abc
>   def
>   ghi

Output:

> cba
>   fed
>   ihg

How to modify it?

```
import java.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = new String();

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            s += in.nextLine() + "\n";
        }

        StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer(s);
        r = r.reverse();
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to post your code, please make it compilable.

Comment: This question has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reversing the characters in the string. You need to reverse the characters on each line.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = new String();

while(in.hasNextLine()){
     StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(in.nextLine());
     s += buf.reverse() + "\n";
}
System.out.println(s);
```