# Java program to find a pallindrome

Tags: java, bluej

I am a beginner in Java programming.
I was a making a program to find if the entered word is a pallindrome or not can someone please tell me the logic i should use to make the given program?

Comment: google it!!! :)

Comment: typing that exact question into google gives you plenty of results

Comment: Basically a palindrome is a word where the last character is equal to the first character. The second from the front equals the second from the rear and so on... Do you see the pattern? ;-)

Comment: You should really try to find a solution first and come back here when you are stuck and need help. For a simple solution try iterating over your input from both directions simultaneously and compare the characters.

Comment: The easiest way I can think is to reverse the characters in the word and then compare that to the original word. This post explains how to reverse a word in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java#7569370

Comment: Ok got it Thank you friends.

Comment: I answered your question below.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thnxx

Comment: boolean isPalindrome = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString().equals(input);

Comment: Thnxx to all  bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
    for (int i=0; i < input.length() / 2; ++i) {
        if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(input.length() - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This solution is self explanatory, the only edge case requiring explanation is what happens for words with an odd number of letters.  For an input containing an odd number of letters, the middle element will not be touched by the loop, which is OK because it has no effect on whether the input is a palindrome.