# Create password for user that consists of surname written backwards, followed by a star, age, then a star, then first name written backwards

Tags: java, variables, bluej, password-encryption, change-password

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    String firstName = "";
    double age =0;    
    String surname ="";
    String password ="";

   Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
   firstName= scan.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
   age=scan.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Please enter your surname:");
   surname= scan.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Please enter your password:");
   password=scan.nextLine();
```

}

Do i create another variable for surnameBackwards?

Comment: You can use StringUtils.reverse (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) over surname. You can create a new String surnameBackwards to receive the reversed value and the rest of the password as you wish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String surnameBackwards = StringUtils.reverse(surname) + "*" + age + "*" + StringUtils.reverse(firstName)
```

Comment: thankyou! would i have to put this into a method? or set the password to the above

Comment: I don't know your requirements. So you do what fits you best.