# Using for loops, how to reverse a string?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans-8

This code isn't working. Can you tell me what's wrong and why?

```
package exer0403e08;


public class EXER0403E08 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str= "hello";
        System.out.println(str);
        char[]strchar = str.toCharArray();
        int first;
        int last=5;

        System.out.println("The reversed is: ");
        for (first=1; first<=5; first++){
            strchar[first]=strchar[last];


            last--;

        } 
        str=String.valueOf(strchar);
        str=str.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(str);


    }

}
```

The answer is "OLLO" and i want to make it "OLLEH".

Comment: It is java not JavaScript

Comment: this i not a jaascript question

Comment: what is this by the way?

Comment: @h.harry Java :) I am just wondering that you wrote the program without knowing the language name you used ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: sorry i'm just a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop have several problems. And you misunderstood the array indexes.

You are iterating and modifying the same array. Hence the weird behaviour and indexces will start from zero for arrays.

So the fixed code will be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello";
        System.out.println(str);
        char[] strchar = str.toCharArray();
        int first;
        int last = 4;

        System.out.println("The reversed is: ");
        for (first = 0; first < 5; first++) {
            strchar[first] = str.charAt(last);

            last--;

        }
        str = String.valueOf(strchar);
        str = str.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

**Update :**

Demo link http://ideone.com/GfgDZ3

Comment: @h.harry output is correct..see changes in above code

Comment: Added a demo link.

Comment: thank you so much. i tried it once but no changes. but in my second trial, it's like magic. by the way, what is the language used?

Comment: @h.harry Java dude. Java.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ i am still laughing for this *java dude java*

Comment: @minigeek sorry i'm just a newbie. i'm very sorry

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own method like this:

```
    public static String reverse(String str)
     {
     String reversed = new String();

     for ( int j = str.length()-1; j >= 0; j-- )
         reversed += str.charAt(j);

     return reversed;
     }
```

and then try reverse("Hello");

Comment: that's complicated

Comment: @h.harry well for your comments on other answer..s.o. is q&a site but a strict one which is why it has quality. Google for it. All the best for coding..and this ans is not complicated just index is reversed

Answer (score 0):

You have better methods in java to reverse string. Please check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7569370/2319627) answer :

You can use this:

```
new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()
```

Or, for versions earlier than JDK 1.5, use `java.util.StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` — they have the same API. Thanks commentators for pointing out that `StringBuilder` is preferred nowadays.

Comment: Didn't think that SO is a tutorial site :-)
And , the question didn't say he just want to learn loops :-)

Comment: ok but our teacher won't accept that. he  prefers using for loops only.

Comment: what's the purpose of asking?

Comment: can you please tell me the language used?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ what's the language used?

Comment: @ArunElectra what's the purpose of asking? What's the purpose of this site by the way? What is its goal? I'm not simply asking. I'm just in trouble why it didn't work.