# Remove duplicated characters from String using regex keeping first occurances

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I know how to remove duplicated characters from a String and keeping the first occurrences without regex:

```
String method(String s){
  String result = "";
  for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
    result += result.contains(c+"")
     ? ""
     : c;
  }
  return result;
}

// Example input: "Type unique chars!"
// Output:        "Type uniqchars!"
```

I know how to remove duplicated characters from a String and keeping the last occurrences with regex:

```
String method(String s){
  return s.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "");
}

// Example input: "Type unique chars!"
// Output:        "Typnique chars!"
```

As for my question: Is it possible, with a regex, to remove duplicated characters from a String, but keep the first occurrences instead of the last?

---

As for why I'm asking: I came across [this codegolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59733/52210) using the following function (based on the first example above):

```
String f(char[]s){String t="";for(char c:s)t+=t.contains(c+"")?"":c;return t;}
```

and I was wondering if this can be done shorter with a regex and String input. But even if it's longer, I'm just curious in general if it's possible to remove duplicated characters from a String with a regex, while keeping the first occurrences of each character.

Comment: I can only suggest reversing a string, [`String g(StringBuilder s){return new StringBuilder(s.reverse().toString().replaceAll("(?s)(.)(?=.*\\1)", "")).reverse().toString();}`](https://ideone.com/9B7vIj).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm, that's a smart approach. Start with the reversed String, use the regex, and revert it back again. I guess using the for-loop with characters is shorter though, but your function is still a nice approach. With some code-golfing it's 110 bytes: [`String h(StringBuffer s){return""+new StringBuffer((s.reverse()+"").replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)","")).reverse();}`](https://ideone.com/1elfz0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the shortest option, and does not only involve a regex, but still an option. You may [reverse the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java) before running the regex you have and then reverse the result back.

```
public static String g(StringBuilder s){
  return new StringBuilder(
   s.reverse().toString()
     .replaceAll("(?s)(.)(?=.*\\1)", ""))
     .reverse().toString();
}
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/9B7vIj)

Note I suggest adding `(?s)` (= `Pattern.DOTALL` inline modifier flag) to the regex so as `.` could match *any* symbol including a newline (a `.` does not match all line breaks by default).