# How to invert a word?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I have a problem in my assigment, I want to invert a word like "Indonesia" to "aisenodnI".

```
public static void main (String[]args){    
    balik();    
}

public static void balik (String nama){    
    for ( i>=nama.Length-1 ; i=0 ; i-- ){    
       balik = balik + nama.Length();
       System.out.print(balik);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Put up a real [mcve]; including descriptions of "what isnt working". And: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your code.

Comment: @GhostCat I try to believe that he simply posted to early

Comment: Have a close look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java

Comment: ..and before he changed `Length` to something correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` for this task, `StringBuilder` would be my choice since its more efficient. its not thread safe so multiple threads can call its methods simultaneously.

```
String reversedString = new StringBuilder(originalString).reverse().toString()
```

If you prefer not to use API support you can do something like this

```
static String reverse(String stringIn) {
    char[] cArr = stringIn.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < cArr.length/2; ++i){
        char c = cArr[i];
        cArr[i] = cArr[cArr.length-1-i];
        cArr[cArr.length-1-i] = c;
    }
    return new String(cArr);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43319617/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: @Dev-iL you are totally right

Answer (score 0):

If only reversing of the string is needed then you can go with the below method.

```
String name= "India";
String reverseString = new StringBuffer(name).reverse().toString();
System.Out.Println("reversed sstring is "+reverseString );
```

Comment: Should be `System.out.println`.