# reversing text in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to reverse a string in Java but I get an error I don't understand when I run it:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at ReversingText.reverse(ReversingText.java:13)
at ReversingText.main(ReversingText.java:27)"
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReversingText {

    public static String reverse(String text) {
        int i = (text.length() - 1);

        String letter = "";

        while (i >= 0) {

            char character = letter.charAt(i);

            letter += character;
            i--;

        }

        return letter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
        String text = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
    }

}
```

Not sure where the problem is, as I think index starts at 0 so I decrease length of the string by 1 to find index?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi Elly. your program is now working. please upvote or correct the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to get the character of variable `letter` (which starts as an empty string, therefore with no length and thus no valid index) instead of `text`:

```
char character = letter.charAt(i);
```

Try this:

```
char character = text.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

There were other mistakes. This is the correct programme.

```
public class ReversingText {
    public static String reverse(String text) {
            int i = (text.length() - 1);
            String letter = text;
            String reverseletter = "";
            while (i >= 0) {
                char character = letter.charAt(i);
                reverseletter += character;
                i--;
            }
            return reverseletter;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
            String text = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
        }
}
```

Comment: What mistakes? Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes wil explain. Please correct my answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: These 2 lines were the cause of problem. String letter = text;
      I have made a new string variable to pick up reverse value.      String reverseletter = "";       You were taking old string letter value only. so old original and reverse string were appending to each other. by creating new reverseletter variable, it solves the problem. thanks:)

Comment: @flogy you can make my answer correct. If it solves the programme.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so I can't.

Comment: OP means what? output?

Comment: "Original poster". I did not ask this question, but @Elly.

Comment: Oh sorry  I am in too hurry. ;)   @Elly  you got the solution??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146303/discussion-between-pradeep-singh-and-flogy).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are finding the char at index `i` in the empty String `letter`. When the `while` loop runs for the first time, `i = 3` and there is no char at index 3 in `letter`.

Instead, call `charAt(i)` on `text`:

```
public static String reverse(String text) {
    int i = text.length() - 1;

    String letter = "";

    while (i >= 0) {
        char character = text.charAt(i);
        letter += character;
        i--;
    }

    return letter;
}
```

Alternatively, for a much simpler way of reversing text, use:

```
public static String reverse(String text) {
    return new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString();
}
```

See also: [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Upvote for also mentioning easy solution and link to related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip:

In the end, remember to close the reader.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
    String text = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
    reader.close(); // add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem were in this line: char character = letter.charAt(i);
You've worked with letter instead of text)

**Here is the working code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReversingText {

    public static String reverse(String text) {
        int i = text.length()-1;
        System.out.println("length: " + i);

        String letter = "";

        while (i >= 0) {

            char character = text.charAt(i);

            letter += character;
            i--;

        }

        return letter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
        String text = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
    }

}
```

Comment: run the porgram. if you will want to reverse of pradeep you will get this result.     pradeeppeedarp. So need to change little more as in my code. ;)

Comment: Hmm. Thats fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem at this line:

```
char character = letter.charAt(i);
```

You should manipulate with `text` variable instead of `letter` :

```
char character = text.charAt(i);
```

Also you can achieve that in another approach using `Stack` data structure:

```
public static String reverse(String text) {
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
    String rtext = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        st.push(text.charAt(i));
    }
    while(!st.empty()){
        rtext = rtext + st.pop();
    }
   return rtext;
}
```