# Facing difficulty java program which reads text in a text box and prints it upside down on am message dialog box using JOptionPane

Tags: java, string, reverse, joptionpane, flip

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class ClassPractice {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String original, reverse = "";
        original = showInputDialog("Enter a string to reverse");
        int length = original.length();
        int size = length - 1;
        for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
        }
        showMessageDialog(null, "Reverse of entered string is: " + reverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you're running into?  It looks like you're currently mirroring it, so `1234` would become `12344321`.  Also take a look at [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I want to flip each and every character of my input string upside down.. The boundaries are that i have have to do it with JOptionPane.. Usage of JFrame or JPanel is restricted.

Comment: Do you have a way to render upsidedown characters?  Reversing the string will only work left-to-right, not up-to-down.  What does the rest of your code look like?  You might be able to reverse the `Graphics` that is rendering the characters

Comment: I have to dig something out with basic programming skills i.e. loops, arrays, stacks etc. Haven't worked on Graphics yet.

Comment: Give desired inputs and outputs, either as text in a diagram or drawn in something like paint

Comment: Is it possible to flip a character by help of loop or not ?

Comment: Please explain with a picture or diagram what "flipped is.  It's definitely possible, but is a lot more difficult based on what kind of flipped you need