# How to reverse a String after a comma and then print the 1st half of the String Java

Tags: java, loops, char

For example String `grdwe,erwd` becomes `dwregrdwe`

I have most of the code I just have trouble accessing all of ch1 and ch2 in my code after my for loop in my method I think I have to add all the elements to ch1 and ch2 into two separate arrays of characters but I wouldn't know what to initially initialize the array to it only reads 1 element I want to access all elements and then concat them. I'm stumped.

And I'd prefer to avoid Stringbuilder if possible

```
public class reverseStringAfterAComma{
    public void reverseMethod(String word){   

        char ch1 = ' ';
        char ch2 = ' ';
        for(int a=0; a<word.length(); a++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(a)==',')
            {
                for(int i=word.length()-1; i>a; i--)
                {
                    ch1 = word.charAt(i);
                    System.out.print(ch1);
                }
                for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
                {
                    ch2 = word.charAt(j);
                    System.out.print(ch2);
                }
            }
        }

        //System.out.print("\n"+ch1);
        //System.out.print("\n"+ch2);
    } 
    public static void main(String []args){
        reverseStringAfterAComma rsac = new reverseStringAfterAComma();
        String str="grdwe,erwd";
        rsac.reverseMethod(str);
     }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to avoid `StringBuilder`? This code currently produces `dwregrdwe` as the output - is that not what you want? If not, can you advise the desired output for an input of `grdwe,erwd`?

Comment: I don't normally use stringbuilder so I'm just trying to avoid any kind of confusion. It does run but try running either line I commented out only 1 element gets printed. It will only output all in the loop

Comment: So it is actually working fine as is, but you want to print the result outside of the loop? The commented out print statements just print a char, so it will only print one character.

Comment: Just an advice, if you create a `String` in a loop, you usually want to use a `StringBuilder` !

Answer (score 1):

You can use string builder as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7569370/3998484):

First split the string using:

`String[] splitString = yourString.split(",");`

Then reverse the second part of the string using this:

```
splitString[1] = new StringBuilder(splitString[1]).reverse().toString();
```

then append the two sections like so:

```
String final = splitString[1] + splitString[0];
```

And if you want to print it just do:

```
System.out.print(final);
```

The final code would be:

```
String[] splitString = yourString.split(",");
splitString[1] = new StringBuilder(splitString[1]).reverse().toString();
String final = splitString[1] + splitString[0];
System.out.print(final);
```

Then, since you are using stringbuilder all you need to do extra, is import it by putting this at the top of your code:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
```

Comment: Ah.. Hmm.. May I suggest you try it. I think that you are making it more complicated by avoiding it... 20+ lines of code vs ~6

Comment: @William I for simplicity I have written out the block of code and described how to import stringbuilder. I understand it may be new, but I think that trying to reverse a string with loops is making it more complicated than necessary! Would you try using my solution?

Comment: @notyou this is only a preference that doesn't make sense. Unless you start using an array to reverse the text, You should not use a String concatenation to do it.

Comment: Agree with @AxelH, notforyuo preferences are terrible

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50436931/4391450) about `String.split` to prevent any problem. The behavior is not as simple as you could think ;)

Comment: @AxelH as I mentioned further down, I just gave the OP an option of how to access the result out of the loops, using their code. I didn’t rewrite it for them.

Comment: @notyou that's not the point here ;-) the point is that some preferences can/should be ignore to provide better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you currently have working code, but are looking to print/save the value outside of the `for` loops. Just set a variable before you enter the loops, and concatenate the `char`s in each loop:

```
String result = "";
for (int a = 0; a < word.length(); a++) {
    if (word.charAt(a) == ',') {
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i > a; i--) {
            ch1 = word.charAt(i);
            result += ch1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
            ch2 = word.charAt(j);
            result += ch2;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/wiLK3T)

Comment: You know the length of the text to reverse, so use an `char[]  instead. Create that many `String` instance just to reverse one is terrible ;)

Comment: Answer has few problems 1) duplicate standard library 2) performace 3) bad style (my personal opinion. mainly because of terrible ignoring basic Java faccts)

Comment: @AxelH and JacekCz , the OP just wanted to have his result outside of the loops, so I just used **his** code to do so. I feel the downvote is quite unwarranted here.

Comment: I agree with you, the comment is there to mention that this is not a good practice, not a bad answer. (Didn't downvote by the way)

Comment: Ok fair enough. There’s enough good answers anyway here to amend now :)

Comment: There is nothing to amend ! Correcting the original post is good for an answer.

Comment: @AxelH oops I meant *not* to amend now

Answer (score 0):

Let propose a solution that doesn't use a `StringBuilder`

*You should knoz there is no correct reason not to use that class since this is well tested*

The first step would be to split your `String` on the first comma found (I assumed, in case there is more than one, that the rest are part of the text to reverse). To do that, we can you [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int).

The limit is define like this

> - If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, **the array's length will be no greater than n** and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.
> - If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.
> - If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Example :

```
"foobar".split(",", 2) //      {"foobar"}
"foo,bar".split(",", 2) //     {"foo", "bar"}
"foo,bar,far".split(",", 2) // {"foo", "bar,far"}
```

So this could be used at our advantage here :

```
String text = "Jake, ma I ,dlrow olleh";
String[] splittedText = text.split( ",", 2 ); //will give a maximum of a 2 length array
```

Know, we just need to reverse the second array if it exists, using the simplest algorithm.

```
String result;
if ( splittedText.length == 2 ) { //A comma was found
    char[] toReverse = splittedText[1].toCharArray(); //get the char array to revese
    int start = 0;
    int end = toReverse.length - 1;
    while ( start < end ) { //iterate until needed
        char tmp = toReverse[start];
        toReverse[start] = toReverse[end];
        toReverse[end] = tmp;

        start++; //step forward
        end--; //step back
    }
    result = new String( toReverse ) + splittedText[0];
}
```

This was the part that should be done with a `StringBuilder` using

```
if ( splittedText.length == 2 ){ 
    result = new StringBuilder(splittedText[1]).reverse().toString() + splittedText[0];
}
```

And if there is only one cell, the result is the same as the original text

```
else { //No comma found, just take the original text
    result = text;
}
```

Then we just need to print the result

```
System.out.println( result );
```

> hello world, I am Jake