# How to change java string direction from ltr to rtl?

Tags: java, right-to-left, direction

I'm trying to change `direction` from `ltr` to `rtl` to the string using java programming language  . 
My string

```
String newString = "\nالفرع: الفرع الرئيسي\n" +
            "***********************************\n" +
            "التاريخ والوقت: 2019/01/0218:01\n" +
            "نوع الحركة: مبيعات مضخات  \n" +
            "رقم الفاتورة: 14\n" +
            "طريقة الدفع: نقد  \n" +
            "المضخة: م 1 ك 1\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "نوع الوقود: بنزين 95\n" +
            "الكمية: 2.830\n" +
            "السعر: 1.060\n" +
            "الإجمالي: 3.000\n" +
            "\n" +
            "***********************************\n" +
            "          شكرا لزيارتكم\n" +
            " \n" +
            " ";
```

Comment: a string is neither "ltr" nor "rtl"... a string is a collection of chars.

Comment: @Mischa , so how can i change direction ?

Comment: `new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString()` will reverse the string and thus change direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @Lino 
This not correct  .

Comment: please check the tag again, this has nothing to do with `direction` and `rtl`, next time you should check the description of the tag before adding it into question

Comment: What do you mean by left to right? Per line? Then you could split the string into a list of strings, reverse each line by itself and put it back together. But your question is currently not really clear to me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with RTL and LTR. What you want is `alignment` which can be done using `String.format` as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to change the format, which requires change in the string. Use String.format with a given width which will add the necessary spaces to align your string to the right or left as you need:

```
static String align(String str, int width, boolean right){
    String[] temp = str.split("\n");
    String frmt = "";
    if(right){
        frmt = "%" + width + "s";
    }
    else{
        frmt = "%-" + width + "s";
    }

    for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
        temp[i] = String.format(frmt, temp[i]);
    return String.join("\n", temp);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newString = "\nالفرع: الفرع الرئيسي\n" +
                "***********************************\n" +
                "التاريخ والوقت: 2019/01/0218:01\n" +
                "نوع الحركة: مبيعات مضخات  \n" +
                "رقم الفاتورة: 14\n" +
                "طريقة الدفع: نقد  \n" +
                "المضخة: م 1 ك 1\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "نوع الوقود: بنزين 95\n" +
                "الكمية: 2.830\n" +
                "السعر: 1.060\n" +
                "الإجمالي: 3.000\n" +
                "\n" +
                "***********************************\n" +
                "          شكرا لزيارتكم\n" +
                " \n" +
                " ";
    System.out.println(align(newString, 35, false));

}
```

Width here is set to 35, you can set it to whatever you need.  ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶-̶`̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶a̶l̶i̶g̶n̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶.̶ ̶

---

Edit: I changed it further, the function is now called `align` and accepts a new parameter `right` which tells it whether to align to right or left as can be seen when changing the `frmt` variable.

---

Edit 2: the `-` sign will align to left if the language is ltr and it will align to right if the language is rtl. Arabic (shown in your example) is rtl and therefore, you need to align in opposite to what you have in English. I have updated the function with the corrected code. For RTL languages (Arabic), use `align(string, width, false)` and for LTR languages use `align(string, with, true)`