# basic Java coding question about reversing order of words for JAVA

Tags: java, string, reversing

I am looking for a way to reverse the word in java.
This is my code and it occurs errors.

Can somebody explain why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Robot {

    public static void reverse(String text) {
        int leng = text.length();
        int i = 0;
        while (leng-i>=0){System.out.print(text.charAt(leng-i));
        i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in your text: ");
        String text = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("In reverse order: ");
        reverse(text);
    }

}
```

I expected it to reverse the order of the word but it does not.

Comment: always include input, current output and expected output in question. It help in fast debug

Comment: Remember that the first character is 0, while the last character is at index (length-1), *not* length.

Comment: "and it occurs errors" please [edit] your question and add errors to the question, so other people facing them would be able to find this question along and possible answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @alea it's a specific problem, not a general "how to reverse a string" question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
int i = 1;
```

Otherwise, you will be getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` since `text.length()` is never a valid index.

To make it a bit shorter (and cooler), you might want to write

```
System.out.print(text.charAt(leng - i++));
```

Though, [we usually do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

```
System.out.print(new StringBuilder(text).reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

`int leng = text.length();`

arrays in java are 0-indexed, which means that the last character in the string is at index (`text.length()-1`), instead of `text.length()`

So, you can set `leng` to `text.length()-1`, or you can set `i` to `1`

Comment: you don't want to set `leng` to `text.length() - 1` - you couldn't call it `leng` anymore ;)