# Add 10 names to array list and print them in reverse order using lamda expression

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

This is what I've been trying:

```java
public class Assignement2_java8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("infosys");
        al.add("wipro");
        al.add("tcs");
        al.add("amazon");
        al.add("microsoft");
        al.add("google");
        al.add("acctenture");
        al.add("hcl");
        al.add("flipkart");
        al.add("apple");

        al.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n.reverse()));
    }
}
```

I know I can use an array of words then store it in ArrayList but I want to know why I can't use this.

Comment: The `reverse` method cannot be resolved on `n` because `n` is of type `String`, and `String` doesn't have such a method.

Comment: If you do a little research here on Stack Overflow you'll find [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7569335/5698098) showing you how to reverse a string. This is then what you need to use for each `n`.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish (giving a specific expected output example). Do you want to reverse the order of your list items (e.g. "infosys", ..., "apple" => "infosys", ..., "apple") or do you want to reverse each String element (e.g.  "infosys", ..., "apple" => "sysofni", ..., "elppa")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add 10 names to array list and print them in reverse order using lamda expression.

ArrayList does not have a reverse method.  Create your own `Consumer` that takes a `List` as an argument.

```
Consumer<List<String>> reversePrint = lst-> {
    for (int i = lst.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
         System.out.println(lst.get(i));
    }
};
            
reversePrint.accept(al);
```

Prints

```
apple
flipkart
hcl
acctenture
google
microsoft
amazon
tcs
wipro
infosys
```

If you want to print each string in reverse (which is different than what your title says), then you can do it like this.

```java
al.forEach(n -> System.out.println(new StringBuilder(n).reverse()));
```

Prints

```
sysofni
orpiw
sct
nozama
tfosorcim
elgoog
erutnetcca
lch
trakpilf
elppa
```