# Fastest Way To Reverse Long Java

Tags: java, reverse, long-integer

What's the fastest way to reverse a `Long` value?

For example, `9876543210` should return `0123456789`.

This is what I have right now:

```
long n = 0, c = 987654321 * 10; // *10 is to get 9876543210 as long value;
while (c > 0) n = n * 10 + c % 10;
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: "**10 is to get 9876543210 as long value;*" - you can just do `9876543210L`.

Comment: Convert the long value to a string, then reverse the string. See [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: That leading zero will get stripped every time if you keep it as a long.

Answer (score 3):

Your program encounters an infinite loop because you never change the value of `c`. Add `c /= 10` at the end of each iteration and it will work, albeit the leading zero will be dropped due to it being a number.

```
long n = 0, c = 9876543210L; 
while (c > 0){
    n = n * 10 + c % 10;
    c /= 10;
}
System.out.println(n);
```

If you need to have the leading zero, you should consider using `String`s instead.

```
long c = 9876543210L;
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (c > 0){
    sb.append(c % 10);
    c /= 10;
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: wouldn't it be faster anyawy to go with String.fromValue() and then revert that? No calculations involved just "array" operations...

Comment: @FrankHopkins What do you suggest?

Comment: @FrankHopkins - I'm not sure that it necessarily would be.  Long -> String conversion does repeated division by 10 and modulus 10 under the hood.  Why don't you try an experiment?

Comment: darn, sorry... I edited your answer instead of mine... will look for the undo button...

Comment: @FrankHopkins No worries.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be fast

```
long x = 1234567890L;
String reversed = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(x)).reverse().toString();

// reversed = "0987654321"
```

---

If You want to convert a reversed value to a `long` again:

```
long x = -1234567890000L;
StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(x)).reverse();

System.out.println(reversed); // 0000987654321-

if (reversed.charAt(reversed.length() - 1) == '-') //remove `-` at last position
{
    reversed.setLength(reversed.length() - 1);
}

while (reversed.charAt(0) == '0') //remove all `0` at the beginning 
{
    reversed.replace(0, 1, "");
}

System.out.println(reversed); // 987654321

long newLong = Long.parseLong(reversed.toString());
```

Comment: @georgezhang006 Note that going back to `long` from the `String`, e.g. by `Long.parseLong(reversed)` might drop leading zeroes, resulting in `987654321`.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I don't know how questioner wants to use this reversed value but if as a number It is important to trim `0` at the beginning and `-` at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert to string and then revert the String, in particular if you want string output in the end anyway. This should be quite straight forward and it has the leading 0, it might also be faster than doing calculations for each positions (but the cost of conversion in valueOf might cancel that advantage):

```
    long c = 9876543210L;
    String cAsString = String.valueOf(c);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < cAsString.length(); i++) {
        builder.append(cAsString.substring(cAsString.length() - (i + 1), cAsString.length() - i));
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

or as a one liner

```
    long c = 9876543210L;
    String reverted = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(c)).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(reverted);
```

I did a little comparison between the options of the current answers:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    for (long i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
        stringbuilderWithDirectCalcs(i);
    }
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, Instant.now());
    System.out.println("Took " + duration);
}


protected static void stringbuilderWithDirectCalcs(long value) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (value > 0) {
        sb.append(value % 10);
        value /= 10;
    }
    // System.out.println(sb.toString());
}


protected static void stringbuilderConvenient(long value) {
    String reverted = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(value)).reverse().toString();
    //System.out.println(reverted);
}


protected static void stringbuilderHandCrafted(long value) {
    String cAsString = String.valueOf(value);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < cAsString.length(); i++) {
        builder.append(cAsString.substring(cAsString.length() - (i + 1), cAsString.length() - i));
    }
    //System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

I did three runs each. The outcome:

```
stringbuilderConvenient
Took PT6.988S /  Took PT6.8S / Took PT6.68S


stringbuilderWithDirectCalcs:
Took PT6.17S / Took PT6.776S / Took PT6.692S


stringbuilderHandCrafted
Took PT18.205S / Took PT16.035S / Took PT17.025S
```

So, scanning the String by hand and sticking the StringBuilder together step by step seems out of the question. Obviously Stephen C was right in his comment that the calculations happen anyway when converting to String. But the approach based on Stringbuilder.reverse and handcalculating each position are pretty close (and any difference might be due to minor runtime fluctuations). So, one might choose the StringBuilder.reverse method over calculating each position by hand for readability with about the same performance.

Comment: Except that it doesn't avoid calculations for each position.  They happen inside `valueOf`.  Look at the source code ...