# java: reverse word using StringBuffer without using String.split

Tags: java

About reverse word using StringBuffer without using String.split.
For example
reverse
Hello world
The output must

```
    olleh dlrow
```

not

```
    dlrow olleh
```

any idea to make this program??

Comment: What already have you done? Please post some code...

Comment: looks like homework, smells like homework...

Comment: my code only can print"dlrow olleh"...

Comment: StringBuffer was replaced by StringBuilder eight years ago.  Don't use unles syou have to.

Answer (score 0):

Import the library and use this function.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

String reverseWords(String string) {
    return StringUtils.reverseDelimited(StringUtils.reverse(string), ' ');
}
```

Comment: Since this is homework, I bet the teacher insist that they **reinvent** the wheel. But the guy could now take a hint and read the source of your proposed solution.

Comment: can without using any import fucnction??

Comment: my teacher said this program using subString and StringBuffer.

Comment: Take help from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-hello-world-in-java and try to do it by wour own.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, so instead of giving you actual code I will tell you what I have in mind using pseudocode.

Assumption: You have to do it in place using one StringBuffer only. Words are separated by space. You cannot use anything other than StringBuffer.

You will need to write a method called `reverse`

```
/**
 * This method reverse the word starting at startIndex 
 * and of length wordLength. For example:
 * StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("hello world");
 * reverse(buf, 0, 5);
 * will result in buf being "olleh world"
 */
reverse(StringBuffer s, int startIndex, int wordLength)

/* Now the pseudo code */
Given StringBuffer sb;
Find all the indexes of all the spaces in sb;
Using the indexes found to calculate the startIndex of each word and the lengths of the word;
call reverse for each of the calculated indexes and lengths;
```

Note: This is only one of the many ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to proceed:

```
User a result buffer to store the final string reversed word by word
Use a temp buffer to store each word you fond in the original string

Iterate over the chars in your buffer.
    // Identify a word: a word is terminated when you find a space
    If the actual char is not space then save it to temp buffer
    If the actual char is a space then you have a word witch is stored in temp buffer
        reverse that temp buffer and add it to the result buffer
        add a space the the result buffer
        clear the temp buffer so you can save the next word in it
```

Here is how it looks like in code

**Removed since this is homework ;-)**

Input:

```
"   HeLlo   world   "
```

Output:

```
'   olLeH   dlrow   '
```