# reverse of a string in java with out using string functions

Tags: java, string, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse “Hello World” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-hello-world-in-java)

How to print the reverse of a string?

```
string s="sivaram";
```

with out using the  string handling functions

Comment: Why without string functions? (Hint: If your starting point is a `String`, it is literally impossible without using at least **one** `String` function.) Is this some form of homework? What approaches have you tried? Also note that `String` is always initially capped in Java.

Comment: why can't you use string handling functions?

Comment: @assylias: Big difference between this and that. This has the unreasonable, unexplained constraint of "no string functions".

Comment: Can you treat it like an array? mychr = mystr[0]?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There has to be one of the 15 answers that does that!

Comment: @assylias: Presumably not, as it's impossible. Directly or indirectly, you *will* use a `String` function to get the contents of the string. Directly (`toCharArray`) or indirectly via passing a string into `StringBuffer` or similar (which will call a `String` function).

Comment: @ assylias no it's not... flip your screen across the vertical axis :-P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you can't access the string, then it's impossible but I doubt this is the intention of the question...

Comment: @assylias: Yes, I pointed this out above. The question is non-sensical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a strict interpretation of your question and that you can't use ANY of the methods provided by the String / StringBuilder classes (which I suppose is not the intention), you can use reflection to access the char array directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    String s = "abc";
    Field stringValue = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    stringValue.setAccessible(true);
    char[] chars = (char[]) stringValue.get(s);

    //now reverse
}
```

Comment: I strongly believe (judging from the question which is obviously homework) that they haven't reached reflection yet in the course

Comment: @user384706 in which case the most upvoted answer is not the expected one either!

Comment: @user384706: And yet, you have to give assylias credit for avoiding calling any string functions! Mind you, he does rely on undocumented features... :-) But seriously, the question is non-sensical, so using reflection and undocumented features in an answer isn't out of bounds. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:The teacher will most likely not accept a solution using material not yet taught :P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder utterly evil, but the OP liked it ;-)

Comment: String.class.getDeclaredField("value"); isn't that a string function?

Comment: Nop, it is in the [Class class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

All functions that access the contents of a String in Java are members of the String class, therefore all are 'string functions.' Thus, the answer to your question as written is 'it cannot be done.'

Answer (score 0):

`with out using the string handling functions`

Sure. Get the underlying `char[]` and then use a standard C style reversal of the characters and then build a new `String` from the reversed `char[]`

```
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
//Now just reverse the chars in the array using C style reversal  
String reversed = new String(chars);//done
```

I will not code this since this is definetely homework. But this is enough for you to get started

Comment: toCharArray() is a 'string function'.

Comment: @bmargulies:The `toCharArray` gets a reference to the underlying characters. It is not a "handling" method exactly.But you may have a point.It depends really on what the OP instructor had in mind

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    char[] stringArray;
    stringArray = s.toCharArray();

    for(start at end of array and go to beginning)
        System.out.print( s.charAt( i));
}
```

Comment: String.charAt is a 'string function'

Comment: without converting the string to a char array it cannot be done

Answer (score -1):

it's not possible to not use any string functions, I have a code that only uses two...

```
public String reverseString(String str)
{
    String output = "";
    int len = str.length();
    for(int k = 1; k <= str.length(); k++, len--)
    {
        output += str.substring(len-1,len);
    }
    return output;
}
```