# How would I print a single index?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, substring

So just to give a little direction,  Ihave this assignment where I am supposed to print out the reverse of the input. Ex: If someone types in dylan it prints out nalyd. I'm also supposed to accomplish this using for loops and sub strings.

Here's my code:

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = kb.next();
    int x = name.length();
    for (name.substring(x,x); x>-1; x-=1)
    {
        System.out.print(name.substring(x));
    }
```

This will print out "nanlanylanDylan" but obviously thats not what I want.
Just looking for a way to remedy this, I understand I could use other methods like charAt and such but I'm trying to use just substrings.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-word-of-hello-world-in-java

Answer (score 2):

`String.substring(x)` returns the entire string starting at position x until the end. The [two-argument form](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) `String.substring(begin, end)` is what you need to chop out a single character. You should also reduce x by 1 initially to be within range. A fixed version of the loop:

```
int x = name.length() - 1;
for (name.substring(x,x); x>-1; x-=1)
{
    System.out.print(name.substring(x, x + 1));
}
```

That extra `name.substring(x,x);` in the for loop initialization isn't doing anything by the way. A fixed and tidied version of the loop:

```
for (int x = name.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    System.out.print(name.substring(x, x + 1));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! i had tried ending and starting on x but i didnt think it would be possible to do x-1

Comment: To add to this, instead of printing with `System.out.print` you can concatenate with `StringBuffer`

Comment: @JustinJasmann Indeed, although StringBuffer/StringBuilder already have a `reverse()` method.

Comment: @Boann Haha, shhhhhh :P

Answer (score 1):

Substring can work much like charAt() if we just substring one character. To do so, we need to get the position of the current letter that we want, and substring that out.

```
String name;
for (int i = name.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(name.substring(x, x+1));
}
```

Note that the first argument to substring() is `inclusive`, and the second parameter to substring() is `exclusive`, so we only get one character with parameters `(x, x+1)`.

```
String name = "John";
name.substring(0, 1); //returns 'J'
```

Comment: Should be `.length()` not `.length`.