# Reversing a string variable

Tags: java, string, loops, reverse

so I have this code:

```
int in = 496;
boolean b = true; 
Sting s = "": 

if (b) {
        int test = 0;

        System.out.print(in + ":");

        for (int i = 1; i < in; i++) {
            if (in % i == 0) {
                test += i;
                s += i + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    } else {
        System.out.println(in + " no factorials");
    }
```

and it prints like this:

> 496:1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248

but I want to revers the factorials output to look like this:

> 496:248 124 62 31 16 8 4 2 1

I tried to reverse the for loop, but it work, so any ideas guys?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-word-of-hello-world-in-java

Comment: Show us the code where you reversed the loop.

Comment: I see `=+` Did you mean `+=` ?

Comment: I did try in the for loop this: `for (int i = in; i >= 0; i--)` and it didn't work, but I see that @Bart answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the loop is indeed what you'd need:

```
for (int i = in-1; i > 0; i--) {
```

By the way, how did you post your code? What you pasted (or typed) does not print any factorials, and `s =+ ...` should probably be `s += ...`, right? Please be as concise as possible, so we have to guess/correct only the real problem, not any typos.

Comment: Bart just beat me to it. that's all I changed in my answer.

Comment: yes the `=+` was a typo and using this method works!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but why won't this work?

```
int in = 496;
boolean b = true; 
Sting s = "": 

if (b) {
    int test = 0;

    System.out.print(in + ":");

    for (int i = in-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (in % i == 0) {
            test += i;
            s =+ i + " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
} else {
    System.out.println(in + " no factorials");
}
```

also, it would help everyone if you used better variable names... once your methods get a bit more complicated it'll be hard to follow 's', 'b', 'i', and even 'in'.

Comment: there was a typo in the line `s += i + " ";` where it should `s += i + " ";` and my apologies I tried to make this code very short since it's just a test code to a larger program.