# Reversing characters in Java

Tags: java

I am studying programming 101 with Java and I am really stuck with this assignment:

"Create a program that asks for the user's name and prints it in reverse order. You do not need to create a separate method for this.

Type your name: Paul
In reverse order: luaP

Type your name: Catherine
In reverse order: enirehtaC"

I can't figure out why my code gives wrong results. Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReversingName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type a name:");
    String name = reader.nextLine();


    int i = name.length();

    while (i > 0){
        char character = name.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(character);
        i--;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: prints it in reverse order. `int i = name.length()-1; while (i >= 0){...}`

Comment: Indices start from 0 and go up to .length() - 1. Your program will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last char is not string.length but string.length - 1

```
int i = name.length() - 1; // you forgot the -1

while (i >= 0) // and the equal sign must be there because if its not you are missing the first letter
{
    char character = name.charAt(i);
    System.out.print(character);
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to [Reverse each individual word of "Hello World" string with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-word-of-hello-world-in-java) which uses StringBuilder's `reverse()` method.