# How to reverse order in string in TCP using Java?

Tags: java

I have written TCPClient.java and TCPServer.java. TCPServer which will simply return the reverse string which user enters in TCPClient. For example:

Input: hello there 
Output: olleh ereht

Now i want to change the order in the strings. For example:

Input: hello there
Output: there hello

Below is my code for only reversing, how do i do to reverse the order?

```
//TCPClient

package orderreversetcpclient;

//TCPClient.java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class OrderReverseTCPClient {
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
   {
      String sentence;
      String modifiedSentence;
      BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      Socket clientSocket;
      clientSocket = new Socket("27.147.162.222", 6323);
      DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
      outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
      modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
      System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
      clientSocket.close();
   }
}
```

//TCPServer

```
package OrderReverseTCPServer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
   {
      String clientSentence;
      //String capitalizedSentence = null;
      ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6333);
      while(true) {
         Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
         BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
         DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
         clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
         String sendToClient = new StringBuilder(clientSentence).reverse().toString()+'\n';
         outToClient.writeBytes(sendToClient) ;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This question likely has naught to do with TCP; isolate the *actual* problem, refine the title, and remove the irrelevant tags. Also, try searching for "reverse each word".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-word-of-hello-world-in-java

Comment: Thats just the reverse of the string. I want to reverse the order. not every characters. FOr example: Hello world will be "world hello"

Comment: See the linked question. (And the problem still doesn't appear to have anything to do with TCP or network programming.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use someting like that

```
public String reverseString(String recievedMessage) {
    // the simpliest splitting. Think about ".,!?" symbols
    String[] words = recievedMessage.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i > 0 ; i--) {
        // Here space symbol may be enhanced to more difficult cases ".?,"
        sb.append(words[i]).append(" ");
    }
    // to delete last space symbol call trim() function.
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Then what do i write in outToClient.WriteBytes(); ??