# javascript function reverse function on parenthesis

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

write a method thar for a given input string, reverse all the letters inside parenthesis .
examples
hellow - hellow

h(hellow)ellow - hwollehellow

for(bar(baz))blim
forbazrabblim
 i stared with this code, but i don't know how to tdo the rest

```
function reverseParentheses(phrase) {
    return phrase.split('').reverse().join('');

}
reverseParentheses("hellow");
```

Comment: What's a *"dab tibah- output"*? Also this doesn't only work inside parentheses, this reverses the entire given string.

Comment: It's "bad habit" spelled backwards.

Comment: You mean [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-individual-word-of-hello-world-string-with-java)? kindly check this. Thanks.

Comment: He wants to reverse the contents of the string. "dab tibah" becomes "bad habit".

Comment: what i dont know how to do, is make that function work only inside a string wich is inside a parenthesis

Comment: @ChristianReyBaron - java !== javascript

Comment: What if the string has more than one set of parentheses? Reverse the contents of them all? What if there are nested parentheses, would the inner ones be reversed twice?

Comment: I think this is not duplicated, it is slightly more complicated...

Comment: @shole at the beginning I too marked this as a duplicate. Once the question was cleared out the owner I gave my final solution too... Everyone is too quick to judge. :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yet many just downvote or marked this question as a duplicate (including myself). Once the question was much clear here is the full and final Solution.

```js
var inputText = "this is a (bad habit) and reverse (todo odot)";
var regex = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;

alert(reverseParentheses(inputText, regex));

// Reverse Text Within Parentheses
function reverseParentheses(input, pattern){
  result = input;
  while (match = pattern.exec(input)) {
      var replaceFrom = match[0];

      // If you don't want parentheses in your final output remove them here.
      var replaceTo = "(" + reverseWords(match[1]) + ")";
      var result = result.replace(replaceFrom, replaceTo);
  }
  
  return result;
}

// Reverse Words
function reverseWords(phrase) {
    return phrase.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are unhelpful.

Comment: Sorry didn't intend to be rude. Was trying to give a quick answer. Fixed it. Let me know should I explain more :)

Comment: With the latest update, this is no longer valid. Let me work out.

Comment: If you find a duplicate, you should mark the question as a duplicate rather than re-posting the duplicate answer as your own.

Comment: @RobG Since the question is clearer now I don't think this isn't a duplicate any more. Wish you could correct it.

Comment: @GerardoLeon The final solution is updated in the answer.