# How do i reverse each character in a string?

Tags: java, string

```
class Solution {
public String reverseWords(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    int current = 0;
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++){
        count++;
        current = count;
        if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
            while(current > 0){
                build.append(s.charAt(current - 1));
                current--;
            }
            build.append(s.charAt(i));
        }


    }
    return build.toString();
}
}
```

I am having trouble understanding why this doesn't work. I went through the 
entire code a couple of times but there seems to be an issue.

Input :          `"Let's take LeetCode contest"`
my answer:       `" s'teL  ekat s'teL  edoCteeL ekat s'teL "`
correct answer:  `"s'teL ekat edoCteeL tsetnoc"`
whats going on?

Comment: Hint: your condition `while(current > 0)` is wrong. Try printing the value of current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems:

- You set `current` to the current position, and then iterate down to 0 append characters. Instead of going down to 0, you iterate until the beginning of the last word. Alternative, iterate until the previous `' '` character.
- You only append something after seeing a `' '` character. What will happen at the end of the sentences? As `i` goes over the letters in the last word, there will be no more `' '` characters, and so the last word will never get appended. To handle this case, you would need to add some logic after the for-loop to check if there is an unwritten word, and append it reversed.

A simpler approach is to take advantage of the `StringBuilder`'s ability to insert characters at some position.
You could track the beginning position of the current word,
and as you iterate over the characters,
insert if it's not `' '`,
or else append a `' '` and reset the insertion position.

```
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
int current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ') {
        build.append(' ');
        current = i + 1;
    } else {
        build.insert(current, c);
    }
}
return build.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder to reverse each word in your String :

```
 String input = "Let's take LeetCode contest";

    String[] split = input.split(" +");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

        output.append(new StringBuilder(split[i]).reverse());
        if(i<input.length()-1)
        output.append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Nice, this works, but OP asked about problem posted code, not for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

First, you skip over index 0. Put these lines at the end of your method to avoid this:

```
count++; 
current = count;
```

You might need a variable to track where the current word began. For example, declare one along with count and current like this:

```
int wordStart = 0;
```

Then, when you finish processing a word, set wordStart to point to the first character of the next word. I would put that after the while loop, here:

```
build.append(s.charAt(i));
wordStart = count + 1;
```

You will also need to change this: `while(current > 0){` to this: `while(current >= wordStart)`

Also: you don't need count. The variable i is the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream-api for your goal:

```
Stream.of(str.split(" "))
            .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + " " + s2)
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: `.reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + " " + s2).orElse(null);` can be simplified with `collect(Collectors.joining(" "))`

Answer (score -1):

This is the easy way:

```
return Arrays.stream(s.split(" " ))
        .map(StringBuilder::new)
        .map(StringBuilder::reverse)
        .map(StringBuilder::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: I removed my comment then (can't remove downvote since it wasn't mine). I am upvoting only answers here which actually address "I am having trouble understanding why this doesn't work". Without that question would be duplicate of many other questions line: [Reverse each individual word of “Hello World” string with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441501)